# How to call a function from map.data.addListener in ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am creating a ionic 3 app where I have a geojson google maps. I need to be able to click on the geojson map and it should give me info related to that particular location. So far I have been able to get only the feature property of that location that is in the map using map.data.addlistener. i need to make an api call after i click the location so that i can fetch the data related to that location. Below is the function that i tried. I can console the basin name but after that i get that this.get_wrf_rainfall_forecast is not a function. Please help.

```
this.map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
    let name = event.feature.getProperty('Name');
    console.log("basin name", name);
    this.get_wrf_rainfall_forecast(name)
});


get_wrf_rainfall_forecast(b_name: string) { 
  let param = { date: "2019-11-07", basin_name: name }; 
  this.api.get_wrf_rainfall_forecast_by_basin_name(param).subscribe(data=> { 
      this.wrf_basin_data = data;
      console.log("basin data", this.wrf_basin_data); 
    })
}
```

Comment: Is get_wrf_rainfall_forecast() in the same class? Can you please post that method definition?

Comment: Yes it is.  this.map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
     let name = event.feature.getProperty('Name');
     console.log("basin name", name);
     this.get_wrf_rainfall_forecast(name);
 });
  }

  get_wrf_rainfall_forecast(b_name: string){
   let param = {
         date: "2019-11-07",
         basin_name: name
    };
    this.api.get_wrf_rainfall_forecast_by_basin_name(param)
     .subscribe(data => {
      this.wrf_basin_data = data;
      console.log("basin data", this.wrf_basin_data);
     })
  }

Comment: In,
 let param = { date: "2019-11-07", basin_name: name }; 

It should have to be
let param = { date: "2019-11-07", basin_name: b_name};

Comment: still giving the error msg that its not a function

Comment: @Koga the error is still the same I am not able to call the get_wrf_rainfall_forecast() function? Can u suggest any other solution